# Stop a SQL query that takes long running time

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

How can I stop a SQL query that is running after it exceeds a specific amount of time automatically?

Comment: How do you execute the query?

Comment: using SET LOCK_TIMEOUT 1800; does not work as expected. It just keeps running and retrieving values

Comment: You could but you probably wouldn't want to... It should be easy enough to monitor for long running queries and executing a KILL command on any offending SPIDs... The problem is that, if that SPID was doing an INSERT, UPDATE or DELETE operation, killing the SPID will trigger a ROLLBACK of that transaction(s). Given that all ROLLBACKs are single threaded, a ROLLBACK can take MUCH longer than the original transaction.

Comment: No Insert or update or delete. Just a normal query to retrieve values